# Is there any way I can animate switching desktops in Lion like it was in Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, desktop, animation

It's been bugging me for quite some time that switching desktops means the application stays at the desktop you're leaving, then pops up on the desktop you switched to. In Snow Leopard, the application stayed where it was and just floated with you when switching desktops, making it a lot easier to keep working in the same window or even to keep watching a movie. This of course applies only to applications you've assigned to all desktops.

I hope this will be fixed in Mountain Lion and if so I will update to that immediately, but is there any way this can be resolved right now, in Lion?

Any and all help will be very much appreciated! Also, I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I've done a bunch of searches but they came up empty.

Answer (score 1):

@RadicalRaid, how I have used the various desktops is to categorize by the projects. so Desktop 1 would be all  project A stuff and Desktop B would be all project B stuff. And if there is a workflow involved then D1 would be process1 and D2 be process2 so on and so forth. That helps me to *focus on a *project basis rather than application basis. On the Mountain Lion Mission control the animations and gestures are much smoother and more organized so that really makes this type of focusing much easier and usable. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this has not changed in Mountain Lion... (At leased not in the latest bata)

I do not believe this is possible for any third party app to accomplish. Apple would have to build this directly into the OS.